# Crossword puzzle focus won't move across the inputs with a number, Tried putting the wrapper and the number in the jQuery function

Tags: jquery, input, focus, crossword

I am making a crossword and trying to get the focus to move right and left with the arrow keys and after a letter is typed, but it gets stuck on the squares with the numbers in them.

This is what my html looks like for the div with the numbers in them.

```
enter co<div><input class="letter" type="text" disabled /> </div>
    <div><input class="letter" type="text" disabled /> </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <input class="letter hideletter" type="text" maxlength="1" value="" placeholder="D" />
      <span class="num">1</span>
      </div>   
    <div><input class="letter" type="text" disabled /> </div>
    <div><input class="letter" type="text" disabled /> </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 //makes arrow keys work, but only works right to left and left to right at this point
$(document).keydown(
    function (e) {

        //makes focus jump to next input when a letter is typed
        $(".hideletter:focus").on('input', function() {
            $(".hideletter:focus").next().focus();


        });

        switch (e.which) {


            case 39: //right
               $(".hideletter:focus").next().focus();
                $(".num:focus").next().focus();
                break;
            case 40: //down doesn't work
                $(".hideletter:focus").next().focus();
                $(".num:focus").next().focus();
                break;

            case 37: //left
                $(".hideletter:focus").prev().focus();
                $(".num:focus").prev().focus();
                break; 

            case 38: //up doesn't work
                $(".hideletter:focus").next().focus();
                $(".num:focus").next().focus();
                break;



                default: return; // exit this handler for other keys  

        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
    });
```

Here is a link to the crossword puzzle.  https://jenniferlang1921.github.io/Crossword2/

Here is a link to my code:  https://github.com/JenniferLang1921/Crossword2

Also, if you have any ideas on how to move the arrows up and down, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: did you tried my answer??

Comment: I did, it worked great for the right to left arrow and the tab, thank you!  I had some issues with skipping an input and I played with it in some of the other places, need to mess with it some more tonight.  I hadn't discovered the document.activeElement yet, so that is exciting.

Comment: If it’s resolved.please mark it as answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will break when the input element with a parent div , because the focus will always goes to next element , means the next element will be always `<span class="num">4</span>`

In order to fix it , you have to check a condition whether the current element has any parent , if has parent change the focus next to the parent

```
switch (e.which) {
                case 39:
              var focusedElement= $(document.activeElement);

               if(focusedElement.parent().hasClass('wrapper')){
                focusedElement.parent().next().focus();
               }
else{
                   $(".hideletter:focus").next().focus();
                   $(".num:focus").next().focus();
}
```

You can apply the same logic to rest of the key strokes you need